# how to call a url that redirect to another external url

Tags: android, url, httpclient

I having a url_msn which is http://www.msn.com and another url_login which is http://uat-hotspot.y5zone.my/applogin1.php. How to call the url_msn which the msn web page is not showing however it redirect to url_login. The problem is I don't know how to related the HTTPClient with this two url. Anyone can help me?Thanks for answering.

Comment: Post what you tried till.

Answer (score 1):

you can use org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.i have used it in java as below

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

String url = " http://uat-hotspot.y5zone.my/applogin1.php";

PostMethod postUsrAuth = new PostMethod(url);

client.executeMethod(postUsrAuth);
```

Comment: ...The PostMethod having error..How I going to solve it?